# How to append multidimensional array to array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We have this arrays,

```
<?php
    $arr1=array(0,1,2,3);
    $arr2=array(array(0,1,2,3));

    array_push($arr1,$arr2);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1);
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Expected :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
)
```

We have tried **array_push($arr1,$arr2)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for "dynamic" multidimensional arrays with `array_merge_recursive` and `array_walk_recursive` functions:

```
$arr1 = array(0,1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(array(0,1,2,3), array(0 => array(4,5), 2));
$merged = array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2);

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($merged, function($v,$k) use(&$result){
    $result[] = $v;
});
var_dump($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 5
    [10] => 2
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: thanx alot! appreciative answer!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in functionality for that. However, you can easily do it with recursive functions or with recursive iterators, for example this:

```
$arrayIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array2));
foreach($arrayIterator as $value) {
    $array1[] = $value;
}
```

it can be done without foreach too:

```
$flatArray = iterator_to_array(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array2)),
    false
);
$array1 = array_merge($array1, $flatArray);
```

Comment: thanx alot! appreciative answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$arr1=array(0,1,2,3);
$arr2=array(array(0,1,2,3));

$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2[0]);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

You can get this with a long way also :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr2[0]);$i++)
{
    array_push($arr1,$arr2[0][$i]);
}
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: the way is good, but its not feasible for dynamically multiple arrays

Comment: Yes I know, my answer is as per the example provided in question. Both arrays can be dynamic or only $arr2 ?

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge($arr1,$arr2);` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote function that gets values from any multidimensional array and I used it in creating result array:

```
<?php

 $arr1=array(0,1,2,3);
 $arr2=array(array(0,1,2,3));
 $arr3=array(array(array(0,1,2,3)));


function getValues($array)
{
    $result = array();

    if(isset($array[0]) && is_array($array[0]))
       $result = getValues($array[0]);
    else
    {
        $result = $array;
    }

    return $result;   
}


$arr1Values = getValues($arr1);
$arr2Values = getValues($arr2);
$arr3Values = getValues($arr3);

$result = $arr1Values;

foreach($arr2Values as $value)
{
    $result[] = $value;
}

foreach($arr3Values as $value)
{
    $result[] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 3
)
```